# Coordinate systems between QGIS and ArcMAp

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, slovenia

My country (Slovenia) is switching to a newer coordinate system and I've received some sample data in this new coordinate system. I went ahead and searched the definition of the CRS on [this website](https://epsg.io). The CRS is [EPSG:3794](https://epsg.io/3794).

**SAMPLE DATA TO REPLICATE THE PROBLEM**:

- You can access the sample data [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=92741554207662241095)
- The url for the WMTS is: http://prostor4.gov.si/ows2-gwc-pub/service/wmts?

---

**ARCGIS PROCESS**:

1. Downloaded the option for ArcGIS -> [ESRI WKT](http://epsg.io/3794.esriwkt?download) and imported the downloaded .prj CRS to ArcMap (version 10.2.1 or 10.3).
2. Restarted the application and reopened a fresh new project.
3. Firstly I set the newly imported CRS for the project by right clicking the "Add data".
4. After that I added the provided sample data (you can find it in the [link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=92741554207662241095))
5. Added a new WMTS connection with the [service](http://prostor4.gov.si/ows2-gwc-pub/service/wmts?) provided by my country in the newest coordinate system, the layer I chose is named "SI.GURS.ZPDZ:DOF050".

**I then noticed that the 2 layers do not align.**

Here is the picture:

[image]

---

Now this got me abit confused, because that would mean my coordinate systems aren't matching. So to confirm my "theory" I repeated the process in QGIS.

**QGIS 2.18 LTS PROCESS**:

1. Copied the [.proj4](http://epsg.io/3794.proj4?download) definition and created my new CRS.
2. Again added my sample [data](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=92741554207662241095).
3. Added a new WMTS [connection](http://prostor4.gov.si/ows2-gwc-pub/service/wmts?) and inserted the layer: "SI.GURS.ZPDZ:DOF050"

**I zoomed in on the data layer  and to add even more confusion the data aligned "perfectly":**

[image: perfect alignment]

Now this made me suspect that ArcMap is behaving incorrectly, but I can't find out why or how.

Comment: Try to load the aerial photo and the shapefile into a new ArcMap project and see if there is any improvement. Maybe the map view of ArcMap was still using the old CRS when you imported the WKT before defining the new CRS.

Comment: I have closed down ArcMap, reopen it, created a new blank project, setted the new coordinate system, added the sample data and aerial photo service, yet the result is the same, I still get the same alignment problem...

Comment: ArcGIS 10.2.1 is now in Retired support status (and wasn't even the final release of 10.2). I would suggest trying a recent release, or 10.2.2. But I suspect that your procedure may be impacting your experience.

Comment: @Vince I tried the same procedure on 10.3 and get the same results... Also could you elaborate on this "But I suspect that your procedure may be impacting your experience"

Comment: It's unclear as to what your procedure has been, so it's difficult to determine what the problem may be.

Comment: Thank you, I will provide a more detailed question!